# If $A\ge0$ and $AB$ is self-dual, then $|\langle ABx,x\rangle| \le \Vert B\Vert_2 \langle Ax,x\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-norms

Claim to prove (exercise 91.7 of Halmos 1958):

> Let $A$ and $B$ be linear transformations of a finite-dimensional real or complex inner product space. If $A$ is positive semi-definite and $AB$ is self-dual (i.e. Hermitian or symmetric in the real or complex case), then $|\langle ABx,x\rangle| \le \Vert B\Vert_2 \cdot \langle Ax,x\rangle$.

*Note: The absolute value in the claim above was omitted by mistake in the first version of the question. The proof in the accepted answer still works mutatis mutandis.*

---

I really haven't made much progress (and I feel like it should be fairly simple), but here my observations for what it's worth. Each path seems like a dead end...

Clearly $|\langle ABx,x\rangle| \le \Vert B\Vert \Vert x\Vert \Vert Ax\Vert$ and $\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \Vert x\Vert \Vert Ax\Vert$.

By the spectral theorem, $A$ and $AB$ both have an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors with real eigenvalues. Say, $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalues $\sigma_i>0$, and $\{f_i\}_i$ are orthonormal eigenvectors of $AB$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i\in\Bbb R$. Then I can write for example
$$
\langle ABx, x \rangle = \sum_{i} \lambda_i|\langle x, f_i\rangle|^2 = \sum_{i,j} \lambda_i\langle x, f_i\rangle\langle f_i, e_j\rangle\langle e_j, x\rangle,
$$
$$
\langle Ax, x \rangle = \sum_{i} \sigma_i|\langle x, e_i\rangle|^2,
$$
or several other variations of the above. The trouble with this approach is connecting it to $\Vert B\Vert$. I do have a characterization of what $B$ must look like for $AB$ to be self-dual. Let $T$ be the orthogonal matrix given by $Te_i = f_i$. Then let $B=CT^{-1} = CT^*$. We have
$$
\langle Ce_i,e_j\rangle 
= \langle Bf_i,e_j\rangle 
= \frac{\lambda_i}{\sigma_j}\langle f_i,e_j\rangle, 
\quad\textrm{if }\sigma_j\ne0.
$$
Also,
$$
\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle 
= \langle e_i,f_j\rangle
= \frac{\sigma_i}{\lambda_j}\langle e_i,Bf_j\rangle
= 0
\quad\textrm{if }\sigma_i=0\land\lambda_j\ne0.
$$
These are conditions on the entries of the matrices $C$ and $T$, and together with $T=T^*$, they completely characterize the possible matrices $B$.

Comment: @user1551 It looks like we are not given that $B$ is self-adjoint, so I don't think we can conclude that $AB = BA$.

Comment: Indeed, $B$ is not assumed to be self-adjoint, so we only have $AB=B^*A$ as far as I can see

Comment: @Milten Is there a source for this claim? Why do you believe that this is true?

Comment: @Milten A potentially helpful first step, assuming the result is correct: 
$$
\langle ABx, x \rangle^2 = \langle A^{1/2}Bx, A^{1/2}x\rangle^2 \leq 
\langle A^{1/2}Bx,A^{1/2}Bx \rangle \cdot \langle A^{1/2}x , A^{1/2}x\rangle.
$$

Comment: @Milten Also, along the lines of user1551's comment, the fact that $AB = B^*A$ implies that $A^{1/2}B = B^*A^{1/2}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann that's not true at all. the reasoning of user1551 does not hold

Comment: @Exodd You're right, good catch

Comment: Ok, the claim is true.

Comment: I previously made an answer to this post myself with a slightly stronger result. I'm replacing that answer with an even more precise result here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820952/smallest-k-such-that-langle-abx-x-rangle-le-k-langle-ax-x-rangle-where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to prove that $A\|B\|-AB$ is positive semidefinite (since it is self-dual).

If $A$ is invertible, then it is equivalent to $A^{1/2}(\|B\|I -B)A^{1/2}$ has all nonnegative eigenvalues,
and to prove it, it is sufficient that $x^*(\|B\|I-B)x\ge 0$ for every $x$, that is true for easy reasons.

If $A$ is not invertible, you can project onto its rank and reduce to the previous case.
In fact, take the EVD $A=QDQ^*$ and call $C=Q^*BQ$.
Notice that $DC=C^*D$ and the thesis becomes the same with $D,C$ instead of $A,B$ and $D$ is diagonal.
Suppose WLOG that the zeros eigenvalues are all at the bottom of $D$, and they are $k$. Since $DC$ has the last $k$ rows equal to zero and it's self-adjoint, you can conclude that $DC$ has also the last $k$ columns equal to zero and thus $C = \begin{pmatrix}E&0\\*&*\end{pmatrix}$  where the zero submatrix has dimension $(n-k)\times k$.
As a consequence, if $F$ is the maximal non-singular diagonal principal submatrix of $D$,
$$x^*DCx = y^*FEy \qquad \|C\| x^*Dx \ge \|E\| y^*Fy  $$
where $y$ is the truncation of $x$ and $F$ is now invertible, so we can reduce to the previous case.

Comment: Excellent! You could also make an argument via limits: $(A + tI)\|B\| - (A + tI)B$ will continue to be positive semidefinite as $t \to 0^+$, and the set of positive semidefinite matrices is closed.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I thought about that, but you can't since you should have a sequence of invertible $A$ such that $AB$ is self-adjoint

Comment: Great point. Here's another alternative: you could also use the fact that $PQ$ and $QP$ will generally have the same non-zero eigenvalues to conclude that even in the case that $A$ is non-invertible, $A^{1/2}(\|B\|I - B)A^{1/2}$ and $A(\|BI - B)$ will have the same non-zero eigenvalues, hence extend the earlier argument

Comment: Ah, thank you! I even wrote down early that we needed to show $A(\Vert B\Vert I - B)\ge 0$, but I didn't think of the square root trick. Hopefully it'll be hammered in better now ;)

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's slick! Also one for the toolbox

Comment: @Exodd: $x^*(\|B\|I-B)x\ge 0$ for every $x$ is false because $B$ is not known to be self-adjoint.

Comment: @ChadK That’s only a minor issue. It suffices to prove it for every vector $x$ such that $x^\ast(\|B\|I-B)x$ is real.

Comment: @user1551: I don't see why, the operator $A^{1/2}(\|B\|I -B)A^{1/2}$ is not self-adjoint either and I don't see the claimed equivalence in the first sentence of the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @ChadK $M=A^{1/2}(\|B\|I-B)A^{1/2}$ is not self-adjoint, but it is similar to the self-adjoint matrix $A(|B|I-B)$. Hence $M$ has a real spectrum. Now let $(\lambda,v)$ be an eigenpair of $M$. Then $v^\ast Mv=\lambda\|v\|^2$. So, to prove that $\lambda\ge0$, we only need to prove that $v^\ast Mv\ge0$. In turn, if we put $x=A^{1/2}v$, then $x^\ast(\|B\|I-B)x$ is real and we need to prove that it is nonnegative.

Comment: Can we make the following variation for a sharper result? Assume $A$ invertible, otherwise project onto the range like in this answer. Let $k\ge 0$ be a constant. $|\langle ABx,x\rangle|\le k\langle Ax,x\rangle$ for all $x$ iff $A(kI\pm B)\ge 0$ iff $A^{\frac12}(kI\pm B)A^{-\frac12}\ge 0$ iff all eigenvalues of $kI\pm B$ are non-negative. I think it holds, and then we see that we can choose $k$ as small as the spectral radius of $B$ (and obviously not smaller than that).

Comment: @Milten yes, I think it holds, but for the future please do not change the text of the question after it has been answered. It only confuses people

Comment: @Exodd About the absolute value, it was always in the title and discussion, it was just omitted by mistake in the main question field (apologies). But my comment was rather about something else! The stronger claim for me is that we can replace $\Vert B\Vert$ with $\rho(B)$, defined as the largest eigenvalue of $B$ (“largest” after taking absolute value).

Comment: yes, that's true

Answer (score 3):

By a change of orthonormal basis we may assume that $A=\pmatrix{A_1&0\\ 0&0}$ for some positive definite matrix $A_1$. Since $AB$ is self-adjoint, $B$ must be in the form of $\pmatrix{B_1&0\\ B_2&B_3}$ when partitioned conformably, with $A_1B_1$ being self-adjoint. As $\|B_1\|_2\le\|B\|_2$, it suffices to prove that
$$
|\langle A_1B_1v,v\rangle|\le\|B_1\|_2\langle A_1v,v\rangle
$$
for every vector $v$.

In other words, it suffices to prove the original inequality under the additional assumption that $A$ is positive definite. In this case, let $H=AB$, $|H|=\sqrt{H^2}$ and $y=A^{1/2}x$. Note that $-|H|\le H\le |H|$ and $|H|=HU$ for some unitary matrix $U$. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\langle ABx,x\rangle|
&=|\langle Hx,x\rangle|\\
&\le\langle |H|x,x\rangle\\
&=\langle|H|A^{-1/2}y, A^{-1/2}y\rangle\\
&=\langle A^{-1/2}|H|A^{-1/2}y,y\rangle\\
&\le\rho(A^{-1/2}|H|A^{-1/2})\|y\|_2^2\\
&=\rho(A^{-1}|H|)\langle Ax,x\rangle\\
&\le\|A^{-1}|H|\|_2\langle Ax,x\rangle\\
&=\|A^{-1}HU^\ast\|_2\langle Ax,x\rangle\\
&=\|A^{-1}H\|_2\langle Ax,x\rangle\\
&=\|B\|_2\langle Ax,x\rangle.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Choosing this as accepted answer, since it explicitly deals with the absolute value. (Both answers are very similar though.)

Comment: @user1551: The polar decomposition is $U|H|=H$, and some of those transitions are inexplicable (2nd line, 6th line.)

Comment: @ChadK What do you mean? My $U$ is just your $U^\ast$.

Comment: @user1551: No it's not.  Your identity is $|H|U^* = H$, not the same as $V|H|=H$ for some other unitary.

Comment: @Milten I think the other answer is better. I typed this answer up after the other answer appeared simply because I wanted to try an alternative answer.

Comment: @ChadK $H$ is Hermitian. Hence $H$ commutes with $U$.

Comment: @user1551: oh, ok.